# Using Jenkins pipeline to build an exising job hangs at "Scheduling Project"

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I have multiple existing projects which build fine. They run `MSBUILD` on a windows agent running the windows service.

I wanted to create a single project that builds them all in a particular order and collects the artifacts from all of them. I decided to try creating a pipeline. When I run it it gets to the first build statement and then just hangs there, no error it just says "Scheduling Project:.." and the little wheel spins forever. The job its trying to start normally finishes in a few seconds.

```
stage('job1'){
    node('windows'){
        build job:'job1', quietPeriod: 0, wait: true
    }    
}
```

I have to kill the build manually, it never starts the job.

Comment: Ok, I think I might only have one executor available and the pipeline is using it. Unfortunately I don't have access to the master. I need to figure out how to configure our agent to have more executors.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I managed to rearrange things so that the pipeline runs on the master and the individual jobs and artifact copies run one at a time on the slave, its working now.